# Trying to use a native package (fuse-native) in an electron forge app & getting a webpack error

Tags: webpack, electron, fuse, electron-forge

I'm playing around with an idea that involves using a library such as fuse-native in an electron app. All I've done so far was simply add the library/import the package in my `main.js` file and run `npm start` (on an electron app that works fine otherwise). I'm looking for understanding on the webpack error I receive:

```
Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:21)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader/dist/index.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| const include = path.join(OSXFUSE, 'include');
| module.exports = {
>   __webpack_require__.ab + "libosxfuse.dylib",
|   include,
|   configure,
```

I tried following [this](https://www.electronforge.io/config/plugins/auto-unpack-natives) and [this](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/using-native-node-modules) and also looked through similar questions on here, but haven't really tried much else because I simply don't understand the error